# Preventing thread pool starvation with a Timer running at same time as Parallel.ForEach

Tags: .net, multithreading, timer, task-parallel-library, threadpool

I have some code similar to the below:

```
long progress = 0;

using (Timer timer = new Timer(state => { Console.Write(Interlocked.Read(ref progress); }, null, 5000, 5000)
{
  Parallel.ForEach(list, item =>
  {
     item.DoTask();
     Interlocked.Incrememt(ref progress);
  }
}
```

I seem to be experiencing thread pool starvation, because the numbers being written to the console are written sporadically - certainly not every 5 seconds.  There might be a long pause of 15 seconds, before three numbers are written in quick succession.  I guess that the timer is fighting the Parallel.ForEach to obtain a thread from the threadpool to schedule the callback on.

How can I work around this?

Comment: What work is `DoTask` currently performing?

Comment: Database processing using Entity Framework's DbContext

Comment: I tried simulating your `DoTask()` with `Thread.Sleep()` and I'm not getting the behavior you're describing. Could you include short code that replicates your issue?

Comment: There may be a bit more to this code sample - I need to confirm first. I think the issue may only occur if I have two of the above snippets, both in Task.Factory.StartNew()s, running concurrently.  Also bear in mind that the Parallel.ForEach loop takes over 5 minutes to run, due to the number of items in the list and the length of time to operate on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I seem to be experiencing thread pool starvation

Starvation is probably the wrong mental model.  The job of the threadpool scheduler is to keep the number of executing tp threads down to the minimum set by ThreadPool.SetMinThreads().  The default is equal to the number of processor cores you have available on the machine.  Allowing more to run concurrently is normally detrimental, the operating system thread scheduler will then be forced to context-switch between them which takes time.

Which is a consideration if those tp threads actually burn core.  This is very unlikely in your sitation when they do "database processing".  That normally involves a lot of dead time, the thread waiting for the dbase engine to perform an operation.

Your Timer callback competes for the threadpool as well, its callback runs on a tp thread.  The tp scheduler allows another thread to run if the existing ones don't complete within half a second.

The net effect is about what you describe.  You don't see a lot of cpu in use for your program and "clumping" is a distinct possibility since that's what Parallel.ForEach() tries to achieve.  You'd want *more* tp threads to be allowed to run concurrently so there will at least be some that can do meaningful work while other ones are waiting for the dbase engine.

Whether you'll actually get that is fairly questionable, good odds that it is actually the dbase engine that is throttling your program.  The network bandwidth is next.  A ticked-off dbase admin that doesn't like you overloading his server is next.  You could tinker with ThreadPool.SetMinThreads() but don't expect miracles.

And do note that you'll need to prevent re-entrancy of the timer callback.  Having the timer tick when the existing Parallel.ForEach() loop isn't completed yet is pretty bad.

Comment: All those problems you describe, they wouldn't affect how often does the timer seem to tick, no?

Comment: Hans, the timer tick is supposed to be reporting how many iterations of the Parallel.ForEach() loop have run every 5 seconds, so isn't it bound to tick when a loop isn't complete?  Why is it bad for this to happen?

Comment: The timer will tick even if its callback is blocked. This can result in multiple database operations running at the same time

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm sorry for bringing this up, but there shouldn't be any blocking in the timer's callback, as they're using `Interlocked` for reading the shared variable. `Interlocked` does make a barrier, and so does `Console.Write` (only 1 write at a time), but I fail to see how that's relevant, and in no way could it delay the output for up to 15 seconds? Could you please explain what you meant? 

I love threads.

Comment: @SpiritBob I didn't say this contrived code blocks. I said that even if the callback blocked, the timer would still fire. This code is simply asking for trouble: `Parallel.ForEach` is only meant for *data* parallelism - processing lots of data using all available cores.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos wait, so if all the threads are busy in the `Parallel.ForEach` with CPU-bound work, i.e blocked, the timer would effectively be also blocked, as it's running on a thread pool thread? Weren't timers being issued a dedicated thread pool thread, hence why creating lots of timers can actually lead to thread pool starvation? Thank you for replying! I think I might be confusing myself - there's no such thing as "dedicated" thread pool thread.

Comment: @SpiritBob it doesn't matter how many threadpools there are when all *cores* are busy. That's why this question's code is simply bad.